# "preseasoned" cast iron pot colors my broth

Tags: cast-iron

I recently bought a certain "light cast iron" that looks like a wok. Cooking on induction, it seemed to give my pork broth a black tinge. Broth was fine, but there was certainly something from the pan.

The wok is supposedly preseasoned, so I don't know why this happens. Any workarounds? Should I rub the inside of the wok with cooking oil and bake it in the oven upside down for 30 minutes?

Comment: I always further season new 'pre-seasoned' cast Iron. My preferred method is: http://sherylcanter.com/wordpress/2010/01/a-science-based-technique-for-seasoning-cast-iron/

Answer (score 1):

Pre-seasoned doesn't generally really mean ready-to-use. It usually only means that the cookware is coated in wax and/or oil to protect it from rusting prior to use. It still needs to be seasoned. [Consumer Reports](https://www.consumerreports.org/cro/news/2012/03/q-a-what-is-pre-seasoned-cookware/index.htm) gets into that and how to season cast-iron for first use. Seasoning is also covered at length on this site.

Don't worry though, the factory coating is perfectly safe to eat as you have.

Comment: Whenever I've seen 'preseasoned', it was coated in oil and cooked.  (but I still give them a couple more coats).  It's the ones that *aren't* preseasoned that are coated in wax.